# Multimaps number of value items

Tags: guava

I want to convert from

`MultiMap<String, String> byState = ArrayListMultimap.create();`
`multiMap.put("california", "San Jose");`
`multiMap.put("california", "San Diego");`
`multiMap.put("california", "San Francisco");`
`multiMap.put("Texas", "Austin");`

to

`Map<String, Integer> numberOfCitiesByState = Maps.immutableEntry("california",3).immutableEntry("Texas", 1).build()`

Is there any guava api to do this in an elegant manner ?

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: You have not yet accepted answers to any of your questions.  You need to do so (click on the checkmark next to the answer that best answers your question)if you want to continue to get interest in your questions.  And you can upvote *every* answer that you found helpful or constructive.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't actually need a `Map<String, Integer>`, you could just call `byState.keys()` and get a `Multiset<String>` which should have the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

simply calling:

```
byState.get(stateName).size();
```

seems simple enough.